# Not expected behavior while setting a string with short-circuit evaluation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, short-circuiting

I want to use this short-circuit evaluation to report a nice status of multiple items in an one liner. But the result is not as expected as shown below:

```js
var items = [{
    "id": 1,
    "available": true
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "available": false
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "error": "Server not found for that TLD"
}];

items.forEach(function(item) {
 console.log(item.id, item.error || item.available ? "Available" : "Not available");
});
```

This produced the following log:

```
1 "Available"
2 "Not available"
3 "Available"
```

At `3` I expected it to show the error because item.error is a string and should evaluate to `true, why does it skip it to item.available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item.error || item.available` is truthy.

You need parentheses:

```
item.error || (item.available ? "Available" : "Not available")
```

Answer (score 1):

As @SLaks said parentheses will fix the problem.  The order of operations is different than you expected.  The || is evaluated before the ternary operator.

You can see the order here.  Logical OR is just above the conditional operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence